# Did the Mario Stretching minigame before the Press Start screen do anything?

Tags: super-mario-64

In Mario 64, before the start button screen shows, you have some kind of mini-game where you could strech marios face in many ways.

[image]

Did that mini game do anything? Had any effect on the main game? Or was it just for show/fun?

I think I've heard somewhere that some stretch patterns would be cheatcodes, but couldn't find confirmation anywhere.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> As Super Mario 64 was Nintendo's first title for the Nintendo 64, an interactive Mario face served to familiarize the player to the Nintendo 64 controller without worrying about actual gameplay.

[Source.](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario%27s_face)

This is the only thing I could find in a quick search. It seems unlikely to be a method for entering cheat codes as there are countless ways and degrees to stretch Mario's face, so there doesn't seem to be a way to put in a precise pre-defined stretch combination.

Comment: From what I remember, this screen was purely for fun.  I don't remember it ever doing anything else.

Comment: As I recall, they used it as inspiration for a mini game in at least one of the Mario Party games, or was it the other way around, but that's it.

Comment: @Ryan "As Super Mario 64 was Nintendo's first title for the Nintendo 64" - I don't know how it could have been the other way around.

Comment: @RobWatts: I think "the other way around" he meant was that one of the Mario Party games might have been an inspiration for this screen.  (Whether that is true or not, I think that may be what Ryan was suggesting.)  However, to answer your question, here is how something like that could be the other way around: "As the NES was Nintendo's first system to debut the game "Super Mario Bros. 3"...  (and SMAS being the 2nd incarnation, and GBA being the third system with Super Mario Advance 4)

Comment: @RobWatts - they're both by Nintendo, and it's likely that Mario Party was in development before the N64 released, albeit at an early stage. It's not impossible that the minigame was developed early for Mario Party, and then adapted to serve as the Mario 64 start screen not long before the game went gold. Of course, I'd call it unlikely, but it's not impossible.

Comment: @Aielyn Mario Party was made by Hudson Soft, not Nintendo. The collaboration between the two companies began in 1998, two years after Mario 64 came out, and Mario Party was released in December of that year (in Japan). So Rob Watts is quite right, the Mario 64 title screen *must* have come first. [Source](http://www.siliconera.com/2010/08/24/mario-party-team-absorbed-by-nintendo/)

Comment: @daemonaka - ah, I'd forgotten about Hudson Soft being involved. But that said, it doesn't mean that Mario Party planning wasn't ongoing before the release of the 64 - just that the actual development happened in 1998. Remember, many Nintendo/third party collaborations involve Nintendo working with the third party studio, rather than the third party studio doing everything with Nintendo funding. But as I said, it's unlikely that Mario Party influenced Mario 64.